# C3867 : '_com_error::Description': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, com, try-catch

i want to catch exception while connecting to Database and I'm using try catch, i use pointer but anyway it gives me such kind of error.
`C3867  '_com_error::Description': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`. also there is not red line on e.Description, it just gives me this massage in error list.
What is solution? Thank you in advance.

```
try
{

}
catch (_com_error &e)
{
    printf(e.Description);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_com_error::Description is a function.

you need to use the ():

```
try 
{
}
catch (_com_error &e)
{
    printf(e.Description());
}
```

On a sidenote: Description() returns a _bstr_t, which might not work well with printf()...

Comment: thank you. but what can i use instead of printf? im new in C++. thank you in advance

Comment: Unclear. What do you want to do ? Just put it out to the console? printf() is a C function anyways, maybe better: #include <iostream> and instead of printf use: std::wcout << (LPCTSTR)e.Descritption() << std::endl;

Comment: btw, using COM is a VERY BAD way to start learning C++... The COM interface classes are IMHO catastrophic and complex. If starting C++, this will teach you a very bad style and give you the assumption that C++ is extremely complicated...

Comment: how can i display error as messagebox? its not console application

Comment: i know but i have project which use com library :/